WSO2 - Identity server - Changing SSL certificate issue
Whenever we import a new certificate into wso2 JKS, the tenant is no longer accessible and we can’t log in to any of them anymore.
If we create a new tenant after updating the certificate, it can be used without issues, but in case we revert to the old JKS, it will become inaccessible.
The product in use is Identity Server version 5.7.0
[2] [IS]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION

How can we solve this problem? Is there any keystore specific for tenants?
